# configure apache bridge for tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, playframework

I have got two java projects:

1. is a web service, which is running fine on Tomcat 6.
2. the other is a client developed using Play 1.2.4 framework and must be deployed on the same tomcat as that of the web service.

My problem is that when they are deployed as a war file on tomcat, client request URL's don't include the application context and thus the path could not be found.

I read as it is possible to make Apache a bridge for tomcat will solve the problem but don't know how to configure it.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is that your UI, developed with Play, is deployed under a context like /myapp.

You have two options:

1. rename the WAR file to ROOT.war. Tomcat will deploy it to /
2. Use Apache as Proxy and implement a Redirect

Apache config would look like:

```
RedirectMatch "^/$" /myapp
ProxyPass /myapp http://tomcatserver:8080/myapp
```